# AMAZON AWS and Python

Tags: python, memory

I have an EC2 instance with 1GB of memory. I have installed tensorflow, numpy, and pandas but when I tried to install `statsmodels` I get "MemoryError".

I also installed Anaconda but removed .sh file using rm Anaconda_filename.

Comment: Er, no. `df -h` tells you about disk space.

Comment: Quick glace here... `df -h` shows disk usage. Memory usage can be shown by `free -h`.

Comment: `free -m` will give you the memory details. `df -h` tells you about disk space.

Comment: thanks guys. ok so I have 749M left. why am I getting memory error? I did import struct
print struct.calcsize("P") * 8 which returned 64 so I believe that means my python is 64 bit and so is my computer if that helps